# Spring mvc vs bootstrap

Tags: java, bootstrap, spring-mvc

Народ, подскажите где заноза. Есть два контролёра(Spring), первый с @RequestMapping("/") и второй с @RequestMapping("/admin"). Вьюшки сделаны с помощью bootstrap. Суть вопроса: когда обращаюсь к странице с первого контролёра, т.е. с реквестом из только слэша, страница отрисовываетса[image: введите сюда описание изображения] как надо, если обратиться к странице со второго контролёра, то страница отображается текстом(см.картинку).

покопался ещё и заметил, что дело даже не в разных контролёрах(метод в контролёре просто перенаправляет на jsp страницу), а вот в чём:
если url на странице, к примеру такой - href="/side_1", то всё отлично, но если дополнить указатель ресурса, к примеру так - href="/side_1/side_2", то bootstrap на перенаправленной контролёром странице работать не хочет и не важно, что будет в url после второго слэша, параметры или просто такой указатель

Comment: мб проблема в путях подключения bootstrap ?

Comment: Откройте код первой страницы (в браузере, который пришел с сервера), покажите как выглядит тег `<link>` с бутстрапом, потом сделайте тоже самое для второй страницы. Скорее всего они будут чем-нибудь отличаться. Полагаю, что дело в относительном пути, например.

Comment: линки полностью совпадают, подключение bootstrap  локальное(всё как в инструкции), в SpringConfig в методе addResourceHandler пути к css и js присутствуют. решил проблему тем, что во всех контролёрах в @RequestMapping изменил путь на только лишь "/" без доп.ответвлений типа "/admin" и всё заработало. разделение на контролёры происходит с помощью аннотации секуриту @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')") в самом контролёре. тем не менее вопрос остаётся открытым, т.к. от чего такой конфликт не ясно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

при использовании jsp страниц подключение должно выглядеть так: link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap.min.css", если страница html, то так: link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css". т.е. разница в слеше в подключении.